# Change a property if route equals to a certain value, Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I need to change `verticalNavType` property's value if url is exactly equals to `'/admin'`.

I try something like this

```
constructor(
private router: Router
) {
if (this.router.url === '/admin') {
    this.verticalNavType = 'offcanvas';
}   
}
```

But it's change the value even router equals to for example `'/admin/company_profile'`.
How can I change the value only for `'/admin'` ?

Comment: you could try `if (this.router.url === '/admin' && this.router.url !== '/admin/') {`, however, doing what you are already doing works in my apps when i've done the same thing

Comment: @31piy then `/admin` and `/admin/something` would also match

Answer (score 0):

Try using the javascript [`substring` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```
if (this.router.url.substring(this.router.url.length - 6, this.router.url.length) === '/admin') {
    this.verticalNavType = 'offcanvas';
}
```

This will match the last 6 characters of your url string.

Comment: you could also add a length check to be sure

Comment: That could made dynamic if the search criteria is not fixed. It was specifically mentioned that '/admin'. That's why I used 6

Comment: but theres a chance that theres a route such as `/admin/admin` which would also match

Comment: I changed the code in my constructor, but it works for every route, maybe I put it in wrong place?

Comment: do you mean this work for routes '/admin' and '/abc'?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this regex:

```
if(/^\/admin$/.test(this.router.url)) {
    this.verticalNavType = 'offcanvas';
}
```

`^` and `$` means the "strict" start and the end of the string.